# How to process only active user?

Tags: user, opportunity-teams

I have a requirement where I need to clone an opportunity to create another opportunity. I have opportunity team member as related list in opportunity. I can successfully copy all opportunity team members to the newly cloned opportunity. But this happens only if all users are active users. If there is a **not active** user I face this error while insertion..

> first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user: []",

Any reference will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a field on User named `IsActive`. You'll need to test to see if that field is set to `True`. If a member is set to `False`, you'll need to remove them from the Opportunity before cloning it.